# storage name already exists

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am adding a new storage account to an Azure subscription and resource group. Neither has any other storage accounts; however, I get an error that the name already exists. Are these names shared with all azure users/subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#naming-storage-accounts):

> Your storage account name must be unique within Azure. No two storage accounts can have the same name.

So if you're trying to create an account with a name that someone is already using, then it will reject it.

Comment: Thanks. I over looked that. Seems odd that private resources have global name restrictions. Makes me wonder how private they are. :)

Comment: @kevin No problem. :)